# TYPO3 BE list view - CSV export with semicolon

Tags: typo3

When I try to use the CSV-Export in TYPO3 Backend's List View, I get a CSV with comma `,` as separator instead of semicolon `;`. Is it possible to change that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not configurable. What you could do: XClass `\TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\RecordList\DatabaseRecordList` with your own class in a small extension. You only need to overwrite one method that calls `GeneralUtility::csvValues()`. This takes the delimitier as second argument (default: `,`).

```
<?php
// Location of file: EXT:extension/Classes/Xclass/DatabaseRecordList.php
namespace My\Extension\Xclass;

/**
 * Class for rendering of Web>List module
 *
 * @author Kasper Skårhøj <kasperYYYY@typo3.com>
 */
class DatabaseRecordList extends \TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\RecordList\DatabaseRecordList {

    /**
     * Adds input row of values to the internal csvLines array as a CSV formatted line
     *
     * @param array $csvRow Array with values to be listed.
     * @return void
     * @todo Define visibility
     */
    public function setCsvRow($csvRow) {
        $this->csvLines[] = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::csvValues($csvRow, ';');
    }

}
```

And in your `ext_localconf.php`:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\Recordlist\\RecordList\\DatabaseRecordList'] = array(
    'className' => 'My\\Extension\\Xclass\\DatabaseRecordList'
);
```

Then clear your system cache.

Comment: Man, you rock! Works like a charm! I hope hope that the Core Team make it configurable in future versions of TYPO3.

Comment: CSV means comma-seperated-value-list ;)

Comment: @pgampe: The reality is: Excel is using semicolons in CSV files :-)

Comment: @lorenz older version only work with tab, which would be ``*.tsv`` then. Newer Versions of `Excel` (2007+) work fine with real CSV if imported in the data source dialog. Although I do not know whether Excel can handle CSV escaping, but PHP does neither, thus I would not put too much effort into this.

Comment: Now there is a forge issue for this: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86681

Answer (score 1):

Since TYPO3 9.2 this is possible to be configured as there are 2 new settings

- `mod.web_list.csvDelimiter = ,` - defines the delimiter between csv values
- `mod.web_list.csvQuote = "` - defines the quote-character to wrap csv values